# is log1p the "correct" way of doing log scale transformation of charts?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, logarithm

when transforming data to log scale for charting purposes, is it more *"correct"* in some way to **always** transform using `log(x+1)` (henceforth referred to as  `log1p` following numpy/python convention) than with `log(x)` and does it break any common user expectations?

I understand that `log(x+1)` will have better numerical stability if the numbers are close to 0, for instance if they are say a loss metric in DL. in such cases log1p could be a better choice.
which of these design choices are more valid?

1. *always* use log1p to compute the transformation
2. use some heuristic to select between log1p and log depending on the name of the metric and/or the range of values (how close to 0 the values get)
3. put the burden on the user to select between log1p and log (I've never seen any code-free software do that)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `np.log1p`, but I presume it's something like adding a constant to the argument before taking the logarithm.

Comment: @whuber clarified that log1p is log(x+1) following python/numpy conventions